# String lexical rule in ANTLR with greedy wildcald and escape character

Tags: antlr4

From the book "The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference":

> Our STRING rule isn’t quite good enough yet because it doesn’t allow
>   double quotes inside strings. To support that, most languages define
>   escape sequences starting with a backslash. To get a double quote
>   inside a double-quoted string, we use `\"`. To support the common escape
>   characters, we need something like the following:

```
STRING ​: ​ ​'"' ​( ESC |.)*?​ ​'"' ​ ​;
fragment
ESC ​: ​ ​'\\"'  | ​ ​'\\\\' ​ ​; ​ ​// 2-char sequences \" and \\
```

> ​ ANTLR itself needs to escape the escape character, so that’s why we need `\\` to
>   specify the backslash character. The loop in STRING now matches either
>   an escape character sequence, by calling fragment rule `ESC`, or any
>   single character via the dot wildcard. The `*?` subrule operator
>   terminates the `(ESC |.)*?`

That sounds fine, but when I read that I noticed a certain ambiguity in the choice between `ESC` and `.`. As far as `STRING` is concerned, it is possible to match an input `"Hi\""` by matching the escape character `\` to the `.`, and to consider the following escaped double-quote as closing the string. This would even be less greedy and so would conform better to the use of `?`.

The problem, of course, is that if we do that, then we have an extra double-quote at the end that does not get matched to anything.

So I wrote the following grammar:

```
grammar String;

anything: STRING '"'? '\r\n';

STRING: '"' (ESC|.)*? '"';
fragment
ESC: '\\"' | '\\\\';
```

which accepts an optional lonely double-quote character right after the string. This grammar still parses `"Orange\""` as a full string:

[image: Parse of <code>"Orange\""</code> even if a later isolated double-quote is acceptable]

So my question is: why is this the accepted parse, as opposed to the one taking `"Orange\"` as the `STRING`, followed by an isolated double-quote `"`? Note that the latter would be less greedy, which would seem to conform better to the use of `?`, so one could think it would be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

After some more experimentation, I realize the explanation is that the choice operator `|` is order-dependent (but only under non-greedy operator `?`): `ESC` is tried before `.`. If I invert the two and write `(.|ESC)*?`, I do get

[image: Parse of <code>"Orange\""</code> even if a later isolated double-quote is acceptable after switching <code>ESC</code> and <code>.</code> in the grammar]

This is not really surprising, but an interesting reminder that ANTLR is not as declarative as we may sometimes expect (in the sense that logic-or is order-independent but `|` is not). It is also a good reminder that the non-greedy operator `?` does not extend its minimization capabilities to all choices, but just to the first one that matches the input (@sepp2k adds that order dependency only applies to the non-greedy case).

Comment: Note that order only matters when using `*?` (which is *non*-greedy). When not using `*?`, the maximum munch rule applies independently of the order of alternatives.

Comment: Btw: You can get rid of the non-greediness here by using `(~'"' | ESC)*` or `(ESC | ~'"')*`.